# how to find modulus of a number in c#

Tags: c#

how to find modulus of a number in c# .net?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the modulus operator %:

```
int x = 4545;
int mod = x % 16;
```

Answer (score 1):

Via the '%' operator.

e.g. `int i = 10 % 3;` (result: i is 1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this site

http://www.willasrari.com/blog/use-c-modulus-operator-to-determine-even-or-odd-numbers/000166.aspx

Basically the % opearator: x%y